# Javascript parse the htmlstring from clipboardData.getData("text/html")

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I copy/paste styled text from MS word to online text editor. When I use JavaScript `clipboardData.getData("text/html")` to get the htmlstring, I can see the text already been converted to the HTML/CSS style, for example, indent will be convert to `text-indent="10dp"`. and `"\t"` will be replace by `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"`. Is there a way to keey all the control characters in the text?

also, I don't know where are the CRLF from?

From Htmlstring

```
THE BOAT did not sail until late afternoon, but so eager was **CRLF**
Robert Townsend to get home that he thought, had there been a day as long as **CRLF**
this.
```

Original

```
THE BOAT did not sail until late afternoon, but so eager was Robert Townsend to get home that he thought, had there been a day as long as this.
```

Edit

sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear enough before. When I strip the html string, by doc.body.textContent||doc.body.innerText, I still get the CRLF in the result string, so how to get rid of those style markers. Which just like clipboardData.getData("text") did?

Answer (score 0):

Extra whitespace and CRLF are meaningless in HTML, you can ignore them; you'll find hard breaks where it's required (